# How to replace \n with <br /> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a textarea where I insert `\n` when user presses enter. Code from this textarea is sent to a WCF service via `jQuery.ajax()`. I cannot save `\n` in DB as it won't show in other applications consuming the service.

**How can i replace `\n` with `<br />` tag?**

**solution**

Well many of you tried and some got right with Javascript Regex with /g (global modifier).
At the end i had \n inserted twice, i don't know why, my only guess is that jQuery on keypress event created double \n which i debug.

```
$('#input').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        inputText = $('#input').val() + '\n';
        $('#input').val(inputText);
    }
});
```

Comment: usually it's not a good idea to replace it on the client side

Comment: @Teneff, \n is not sent then to the server, it seems omitted. I can change it on server but i receive nothing except of text.

Comment: You should also store it in the raw format entered, if you ever added a new app to retrieve data that could support the /n then surely you should show it? have you tried encoding it?

Comment: is `#input` an `<input type="text"/>`? Because if it is you will not get any `\n`. If it is a textarea I suggest you convert the data when the user clicks the button to submit and not when typing. But better than that I would just convert on the server-side.

Comment: @BrunoLM, #input is textarea and i do replace \n to :br: at submit and turn :br: to br html tag when i get data back from server. Why i'm not doing it on server because besides br tags i have images and image tag is quite long one to send via service to jQuery wrapper so i mark tags i need with colons, alike forums do that with [tagname]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Replace with global scope

```
$('#input').val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
```

or

```
$('#input').val().replace("\n", "<br />", "g")
```

Comment: it replaces fine globally but it replaces twice br tag on keypress

Answer (score 12):

it could be done like this:

```
$('textarea').val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

**edit**: sorry ... the regular expressions in javascript should not be quoted

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmW45/)

Comment: Doesn't work since he wants to replace `\n` and not `/\n/`. And if it was intended to be a regex it would only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: @Qtax, it replaces just first appearance of \n and omits others

Comment: Just use a string replacement, like `"\n"`, if you really want to use regex you can do `/\n/g`.

Answer (score 7):

Like said in comments and other answer, it's better to do it on server side.

However if you want to know how to do it on clientside this is one easy fix:

```
textareaContent.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
```

Where `textareaContent` is the variable with the data in the textarea.

**Edit:** Changed so that it replaces globally and not only first match.

Comment: It replaces just first appearance of \n

Answer (score 2):

If you support PHP you should check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple javascript string function.

```
 string.replace("\n", "<br>")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use javascript built in replace function with a little help of regex, for example

```
$('#input').val().replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />')
```

this code will return all enters replaced with `<br>`

Comment: This is the only one out of this entire page that worked for me for wordpress editor. If you are using a wordpress editor in a plugin, and need to for some reason show a preview of the editors contents, this is the only one here that works.

Comment: Did you really tried every solution from this question, if you did then you are really persistent. :)

Answer (score 1):

From within your WCF service can you not just use `String.Replace` ?

```
text = text.Replace("\n","<br />");
```

Comment: Don't do this! You've to use a regular expression to replace all matches globally. E.g, in your case, it will only replace the first occurrence

Answer (score 1):

```
var replaced = $('#input').val().replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the other answers, this is probably done best by php. Now assuming you don't want to ajax this (which would be pointless and cause unnecessary server load), you should probably use [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org)'s javascript port of [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    // Converts newlines to HTML line breaks  
    // 
    // version: 1103.1210
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Philip Peterson
    // +   improved by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Atli Þór
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman    // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   improved by: Maximusya
    // *     example 1: nl2br('Kevin\nvan\nZonneveld');    // *     returns 1: 'Kevin\nvan\nZonneveld'
    // *     example 2: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", false);
    // *     returns 2: '<br>\nOne<br>\nTwo<br>\n<br>\nThree<br>\n'
    // *     example 3: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", true);
    // *     returns 3: '\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n'    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '' : '<br>';

    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480

Comment: What $1 and $2 mean? ([^>\r\n]?) and  (\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)

Comment: To tell you the Truth, I am not so good with regex as I should be. But the little I do know about this is summed up in these two links: Dollar Signs - http://mootools-users.660466.n2.nabble.com/Moo-preg-replace-in-javascript-td4718179.html; all the r's and n's - http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-format.php (scroll down to the section about replacing carriage returns with html br.  And the code works as shown here - http://jsfiddle.net/Dar96/9/

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace all instances of `\n` with a `<br />` :

```
while (message.indexOf("\\n") !== -1) {
   message = message.replace("\\n", "<br />");
}
```

Comment: One iteration is enough, since it replaces all occurences.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question/answer but it's one of the first to come up on a google search and no longer works here in the distant future with current browsers.

The correct answer to convert the `\n` to `<br />` (at least for me) is:

```
text = text.Replace(/\\n/g,"<br />");
```