# jQuery: add line break at cursor position when hitting Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, cursor-position

I have a form with a textarea (`id = details`).

Is there a way I can insert the HTML code for a line break (`<br />`) at the cursor position when hitting Enter within this textarea ?

I would only need this to get to work in IE.

```
<textarea class="input height120 elastic span12" name="details" id="details" onkeyup="countCharLimit(event)" onpaste="countCharLimit(event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: why would you need that? enter already does that for you :)

Comment: was just kidding above, have a look at my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+"<br />");
    }
});
```

You could try and **[fiddle with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/22GLG/1/)**

**EDIT:** I realized this is adding a `<br />` at the end only, after some more research, I found this solution:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart)+"<br />"+"\n";
    }
});
```

Here is a **[fiddle for this one](http://jsfiddle.net/7PKGT/2/)**

Source (mostly): [Insert text into textarea with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery)

**EDIT AGAIN:** Looks like the OP wanted the text at the end to also be cleared, so I updated my code accordingly (for other's seeing this: check out [the first edit of my relevant fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PKGT/1/) for the case you'd want to keep the remaining text).

Comment: Thanks, this would always insert it at the end of the content not at the cursor position, right ?

Comment: Thanks, this does enter the HTML code at the correct position but then copies my initial content again after that.

Comment: It still copies my initial content again after the line break. Without that it would be fine but this way it always looks like this in the end: myText<br />myText - I would then always have to delete the copy of my text from the end of the string.

Comment: what do you want?? explain better

Comment: try removing the last (,this.value.length) .. it is optional and it could be the source of repeatition

Comment: by the way  i tested your solution and it is working perfect ... i tested it on the chrome.. i don't know if other browsers will give different effects

Comment: thanks, dude, appreciate the feedback! hope the OP gets back here sooner or later and makes a selection... ;)

Answer (score 2):

you will need to find the caret position first as follow:

```
    var caretPos = function() {
        var el = $("#details").get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
```

taken from :[here](http://techniqzone.blogspot.com/2013/05/get-cursor-position-in-textarea-jquery.html)

then you do:

```
var textofDetails = $("#details").val();
jQuery("#detail").val(textofDetails.substring(0, caretPos) + "<br/>" + textofDetails.substring(caretPos) );
```

Major EDIT:

no need for all the above ; your function will be

```
function replaceNewLine(){

    jQuery("#detail").val().replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
}
```

source: [so - here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331895/how-to-replace-n-with-br-in-javascript)

Comment: I am getting caretPos is undefined when I try this. I copied the above into my functions file and initiated it by click on a button. Anything else I need to do here ?

Comment: i edited the code please revise it .. hope it will work

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesnt do anything. Maybe it loses the caret position when I click the button ?

Comment: your major edit was what I tried with first, but the OP wants the `<br>` tag to appear at cursor position... I believe at least, as they weren't very precise in asking the question, additionally wanting to have the rest of the text (I guess what's after the cursor position) removed...

Comment: No my major edit will replace any \n while your first trial was about appending trailing <br> at the end ;)..anyways i am waiting his reply to say weather it worked or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. It seems to be so, that you need keydown event processing and, possible, setTimeout 0 hack, look here: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)