# How to replace the line break in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to replace the space and line break in a textarea, 
if the input is

```
________________________________________
i am a 
fat

boy zzz
________________________________________
```

the result should be

```
i<sp>am<sp>a<br>fat<br><br>boy<sp>zzz
```

where space is replaced by `<sp>` and newline is replaced with `<br>`.

The space replacement is successfully done, 
but i failed when i try to replace new line with `<br>` (i tried 3-4 different methods but none of them can make it)

it would be grateful if anyone have idea? thanks in advance

The code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="70">i am fat boy </textarea>

<input type="text" id="StringTextBox" value="" >

<p id="demo"> </p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("txtArea").value; 

  var res = str.split(' ').join('&lt'+"sp"+'&gt');

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should give what you tried. Just notice that there is different line break depending on the OS. (\r , \n , ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace \n with <br /> in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331895/how-to-replace-n-with-br-in-javascript)

Comment: str.replace(/(\S)/g,"<sp>").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"<br>")

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use `split` and `join` for this at all, just direct replacement. Note that different OSs (and even different browsers on the same OS) use different characters for line breaks, so to cover your bases you'll probably want an alternation:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r|\n|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
```

That will replace each standalone `\r`, a standalone `\n`, or a `\r\n` right next to each other with `<br>`.

And of course, we combine that with `.replace(/ /g, '<sp>')` to do the spaces:

```
str = str.replace(/ /g, '<sp>').replace(/(?:\r|\n|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
```

Gratuitous live example:

```js
var originals = [
  "i am a\nfat\n\nboy zzz",
  "i am a\rfat\r\rboy zzz",
  "i am a\r\nfat\r\n\r\nboy zzz"
];
  
originals.forEach(function(str) {
  str = str.replace(/ /g, '<sp>').replace(/(?:\r|\n|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
  snippet.log(str);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If it were a **really big string** then taking two passes through it (two calls to `replace`) might not be ideal. In that **unlikely** case, we could combine things into a single `replace` using a callback function:

```
str = str.replace(/(?: |\r|\n|\r\n)/g, function(m) {
    return m === " " ? "<sp>" : "<br>";
});
```

Live examples:

```js
var originals = [
  "i am a\nfat\n\nboy zzz",
  "i am a\rfat\r\rboy zzz",
  "i am a\r\nfat\r\n\r\nboy zzz"
];
  
originals.forEach(function(str) {
  str = str.replace(/(?: |\r|\n|\r\n)/g, function(m) {
      return m === " " ? "<sp>" : "<br>";
  });
  snippet.log(str);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

But in the normal case of a reasonably-sized string, two calls to `replace` with direct replacements is probably better than a single call with a callback function.

Comment: nice answer though, makes my answer redundant, (and really not so good) so I removed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in one go by passing a *function* as the second parameter

```
var str = 'foo bar\nbaz';

str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n)|(\s)/g, function ($0, $1, $2) {
    return ($2 && '&lt;sp&gt;') || '&lt;br&gt;'
});
// "foo&lt;sp&gt;bar&lt;br&gt;baz"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the teacher will have a doubt about this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Should replace as you type :)

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"), function(textarea) {
  textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
    textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/\n/g, "<br>").replace(/ /g, "<sp>");
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

It could be done more simply, but I think this could be an interesting thing to learn from.

The first line gets all textareas on the page as a `NodeList`.  Then, we loop through that NodeList with `[].forEach.call`, shortened from `Array.prototype.forEach.call`, because `NodeList`s don't have their own `forEach`.

The second line sets an event listener that triggers whenever the current textarea (in the loop) receives input.  Event listeners wait for something to happen, and call functions whenever it does.

The third line sets the value of that textarea to whatever the current value is, with newlines (`\n`) replaced with `<br>` and spaces replaced with `<sp>`.

Comment: *"Should replace as you type"* Making the text area effectively unusable, as it would reset your insertion point position constantly.

Comment: Oh absolutely, but I don't think this is a pratical problem to begin with.